# jQuery Make Text Change Before It's Noticeable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, text

I'm using the following code to make a text change on a website:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div#sidebar ul.side-nav li.current_page_item a').text('Request a Quote');
});
```

The problem is, the change is done until AFTER the webpage has finished loading, so the user actually gets to see what was the original text before the new text is inserted. This is not the desired effect. Is there a way I can run this simple jQuery command without it executing in front of the user's eyes? The text should be changed before the page is loaded so it looks like it was always there.

Comment: Why can't you just change how it is originally populated?

Comment: That is the purpose of the `$(document).ready` function…

Comment: The CMS doesn't let me change that text directly so I would have to hack the source code. I would rather make the change using jQuery.

Comment: $(document).ready doesn't give the desired affect, the change is very noticeable.

Comment: Using PHP might be worthwhile `<a><?php echo "Request a Quote"?></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the anchor as hidden initially with css. The update your text and show with jquery.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div#sidebar ul.side-nav li.current_page_item a').text('Request a Quote').show();
});
```

```css
div#sidebar ul.side-nav li.current_page_item a {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Bingo! This is the correct answer. The key was how you used CSS to hide the element, since CSS *does* execute before the page is visible. Then you just use jQuery to show the element after the change has been made. Very creative answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could hide it before changing the text, then show it afterward:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div#sidebar ul.side-nav li.current_page_item a')
      .hide()
      .text('Request a Quote')
      .show();
});
```

Comment: If you do it this way, the exact same thing happens; it's very noticeable. tellez's way works because he uses CSS to hide the element first, you used jQuery.